# How to provide JSON input directly as a String argument

Tags: java, json

The following code prints the following as input, but I would like to pass this JSON string as input directly to parse method (preferably as string argument). How should I do that?

{"val1":"v1","val2":"v2"}

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class ParseJSON {

    String val1;
    String val2;
    transient String val3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        ParseJSON parseJson = new ParseJSON();
        parseJson.val1 = "v1";
        parseJson.val2 = "v2";
        parseJson.val3 = "v3";
        String requestBody = gson.toJson(parseJson);
        System.out.println(requestBody);

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        // JsonArray array = parser.parse(requestBody).getAsJsonArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want pass JSON string directly to the parser. I am unable to do that, since the input string is in a certain format as seen by the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON that is being created would be considered a JSON object, not an array. To parse it correctly, you would need to call:

```
JsonObject object = parser.parse(requestBody).getAsJsonObject();
```

A JSON array would look more like this:

```
[{"va1": "v1", "val2": "v2", "val3": "v3"}, {"val4": "v4", "val4": "v5", "val5": "v6"}]
```

That's a JSON array containing two JSON objects. JSON arrays have similar style to arrays you see in Java, they have `[` `]` brackets and contain a comma separated list of objects/arrays/primitives.

Additionally, you can parse it like this as well:

```
JsonElement element = parser.parse(requestBody);
```

Once you have a `JsonElement` you can call methods like `isJsonArray()` or `isJsonObject()` to find out what the top level JSON element is for the `String` you've parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
*You should do that in a following code for your request*

        static String val1 = "v1";
        static String val2 = "v2";
        transient String val3;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JSONArray arrayTable = new JSONArray(); 
            JSONObject node = new JSONObject();  
            node.put("val1", val1);
            node.put("val2", val2);
            arrayTable.add(node);
            System.out.println(arrayTable);

        }

**Dependency lib**:
 <dependency>
    <groupId>json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
    <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```